# JavaScript--How do I easily switch between dot vs. bracket property access in IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, google-closure-compiler

I want to be able to easily switch between "dot notation" and the "bracket notation" property-access using IntelliJ.

For example, can the following following JavaScript

```
var x = obj.a;
```

be converted to

```
var x = obj['a'];
```

and back, in a "simple" manner, similar to the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> refactoring hints? Really, I'm looking for any technique for efficiently converting in either direction.

#### What I've tried

I've created a Live Template that goes partway from "dot" to "bracket":

```
['$SELECTION$']
```

but that leaves the `.` to be removed manually:

```
x = obj.a
// Use IntelliJ "Surround Template"
x.obj.['a']
// Manually remove the dot
x.obj['a']
```

(A similar effect can be made with "Surround selection on typing quote or brace" checked.)

Unfortunately, I cannot go the other way ("bracket" to "dot") with Live Templates because you cannot remove characters in a Live Template.

#### Motivation

I'm using the Google Closure Compiler with the `ADVANCED` optimization flag. Without any intervention, it renames method/object names that are intended to be used externally, and it renames method/object names on external code. The workarounds are

1. Use bracket notation (GCC does not alter strings)
2. Use "`goog.exportSymbol()` and `goog.exportProperty()`" for code you want to export (e.g., your code is a library) as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#export); and declaring "externs" files for external code you are using, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#externs)

I feel that 1. is slightly less bothersome than 2.

#### Asides

- While not all valid "brackets" are valid "dots", an acceptable solution does not necessarily have to account for this.
- This is *not* a question about which notation is better/preferred/etc.

Comment: Just a note on your motivation: currently when using bracket notation, the compiler doesn't type check that property. That should be fixed soon though.